# UI Sharepoint Masterpage help

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage

I'm a front-end(UI) developer and working with my first Sharepoint site. I've been trying to find reliable Sharepoint themes or Custom masterpages that I can use and further customize. Can anyone share any good sites or theme builder engines that I can leverage to style Sharepoint masterpages.

I've heard there is a Twitter Bootstrap theme for Sharepoint but may have some bugs associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not as yet found a good free site for custom branding samples. I have our SharePoint site totally custom branded and I have to warn you upfront, if you are new to SharePoint custom branding can be very tricky because there are a lot of different things that use the standard style sheet that SharePoint comes with. 
However, if you really want to get into it and see what you can come up with here is a couple suggested tutorials. 
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-SharePoint-Branding-Interface-Programmer/dp/0470584645/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1345468568&sr=8-1&keywords=sharepoint+2010+branding](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470584645)
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-SharePoint-Branding-Interface-Programmer/dp/0470584645/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1345468568&sr=8-1&keywords=sharepoint+2010+branding](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470584645)

If you just want to create your own site theme this is a great video on how to easily do this.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tE0rwUaLTzQ